# Darwin to Timor by boat

Tags: australia, ferries, sea-travel

Need a bit of advice.

I can't seem to find any information about boats from Darwin to Timor.
I've been informed there are no ferries.

Anyone know how to or had experience getting from Darwin to Timor by boat?

Comment: Are you in Darwin at the moment? (There are a few things I could suggest you try if you were)

Comment: Nope this will be a trip in a couple months. It is supposed to be an all ground trip from Sydney, up to China, across to Russia, then down through Japan to Taiwan. I have almost everything figured out except this part.

Comment: Suggestions which involve going to see the harbour master are unlikely to work for you then, hopefully someone else can advise / go there for you!

Comment: That is what I plan to do if I can't find a route before I arrive.

Comment: From what I know it's not a all easy to get a boat out of Australia. But it is an adventure travel option that some people manage to do. I think this is a great question and I'm looking forward to any answers.

Comment: I think Mark's answer sums it up, but I'd like to see if I can get another.

Comment: Google Maps and Apple maps say No (to a ferry).  But it looks like you've been offered alternatives.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's hard, but possible.  I think the best answer for me aside from giving links is to just link to you my friend's blog - she cycled from London to New Zealand, and took boats between the land masses. It took her four months of searching to find a boat from East Timor to Australia, but you'll be better off reading about it on her blog, and potentially even contacting her if need be.

[Across The Water....Indo To AUSTRALIA!](https://web.archive.org/web/20160313104817/http://www.bugbitten.com/blogs/Worldwide/kyles/across_the_waterindo_to_australia.html)

Comment: Good blog. Guess it is find-a-crew. I was hoping to avoid yacht crews, but hey.

Comment: Yeah, but unfortunately I think your options are limited there.  Still, ask around when you get to the port or on the websites - you never know, you may strike it lucky :)